# How to add server time using FirebaseStore timestamp?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I'm using Firebase data-base I can set server-time as below:

```
user.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

And then update it.

But if I used the same one with *FireStore* it doesn't succeed, Also I don't need to implement `firebase-data-base` in my *gradle* for only this purpose.

I can see that there is `ServerTimestamp.class` related to *FireStore* but I don't know how to use it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to docs it would be something like this:

```
@ServerTimestamp Date time;
```

If `null` it will have the server-generated timestamp, so you don't need to do set the value for it.

Ref: 
Annotation used to mark a Date field to be populated with a server timestamp. If a POJO being written contains null for a @ServerTimestamp-annotated field, it will be replaced with a server-generated timestamp.
(https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/ServerTimestamp)

**Edit:**

Or when working with a `map` type object directly:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("objects").document("some-id");

// Update the timestamp field with the value from the server
Map<String,Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
updates.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
```

Ref:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects

Comment: Thanks, but it's seems that `@ServerTimestamp Date time;` no an legal syntax.

Comment: That's only to be used when working with classes. See my update if you are using maps.

Comment: Pretty much, Thanks.